# Is it correct to use both "On the other hand" and "instead" in a single sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, redundancy

I have this sentence

> "On the other hand, you can go to this page instead."

but I am not sure if the presence of both `On the other hand` and `instead` makes the sentence redundant.

Comment: It is redundant, but that doesn't make it *wrong*.

Comment: This very question is redundant. But you seem to think that's fine. Which it is.

Comment: I have mustard on this hand and ketchup on the other hand instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(language))

> ... a tautology is a statement which repeats the same idea, using
>   near-synonymous morphemes, words, or phrases, that is, "saying the
>   same thing twice".

As to whether there is always error in it's use:

> ... it is often considered a fault of style when unintentional. On the
>   other hand, an intentional repetition may be an effective way to
>   emphasize a thought, or help the listener or reader understand a
>   point.

Answer (score 1):

All it's doing is unnecessarily restating information, it's not causing a logical conflict in the grammar, so its impact on meaning is harmless. More of a style issue than a grammar one.